# Returning a string array from a web service

Tags: web-services, exception, apache-axis

I have created a web service for the following code but I am getting an exception:

> org.apache.axis.InternalException:
>   java.lang.Exception: Couldn't find a
>   matching Java operation for WSDD
>   operation "andrQues" (0 args)" on
>   invoking the function.

```
public class Ques {
    public String[] AndrQues(){
        String ques[] = {"name??", "age??", "grade??"};
        return ques;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why its occuring or if it should be written in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.
I was using envelope.getResponse() to retrive the returned values. Instead following should be written:

**KvmSerializable result = (KvmSerializable)envelope.bodyIn;

System.out.println("Result : " + result.getProperty(0).toString());**

This works fine to retrive values from an array.